# SQL Management Studio Selecting specific children

Tags: sql, t-sql, join

So I have three tables, `table1`, `table2`, and `table3`. They each have ID fields, `table1ID`, `table2ID`, and `table3ID` respectively. Additionally, `table2` has a field `table1ID` which points to a row in `table1`, and `table3` has a field `table2ID` which points to a row in `table2`.

So, my question is, how do I do a select statement that selects only the rows in `table3` that reference a row in `table2` that reference a row in `table1` with the ID `4`?

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with SQL Management Studio. Although, it is obvious you are using SQL Server and accessing the server via SQL Management Studio.

Comment: fixed tags to match the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking at a link of joins similar to this

```
select * from table3
join table2 on table3.table2ID = table2.table2ID
join table1 on table2.table1ID = table1.table1ID
where table1.ID = 4
```

this will only return table3 records if there is a matching table2 AND table 1 record. The join will filter the results out where the joins match, and the WHERE filter will only select from the results where table1 ID = 4.

A working sample I whipped up (hey I have time to kill)

```
create table #table1 (table1ID int)
create table #table2 (table2ID int, table1ID int)
create table #table3 (table3ID int, table2ID int)

insert into #table1 values(1)
insert into #table1 values(2)
insert into #table1 values(3)
insert into #table1 values(4)

insert into #table2 values(10, 1)
insert into #table2 values(11, 2)
insert into #table2 values(12, 3)
insert into #table2 values(13, 4)

insert into #table3 values(20, 10)
insert into #table3 values(21, 11)
insert into #table3 values(22, 12)
insert into #table3 values(23, 13)

-- all joined records
select * from #table3
join #table2 on #table3.table2ID = #table2.table2ID
join #table1 on #table2.table1ID = #table1.table1ID

-- only where table1 ID = 4
select * from #table3
join #table2 on #table3.table2ID = #table2.table2ID
join #table1 on #table2.table1ID = #table1.table1ID
where #table1.table1ID = 4

drop table #table1
drop table #table2
drop table #table3
```

This gives you

```
table3ID    table2ID    table2ID    table1ID    table1ID
----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
20          10          10          1           1
21          11          11          2           2
22          12          12          3           3
23          13          13          4           4

table3ID    table2ID    table2ID    table1ID    table1ID
----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
23          13          13          4           4
```

Comment: Not sure whether * will return fields from table2 and table3.  What about select table3.* ?

Comment: @StartClass: Yep, it does return fields from all the tables. And what you said fixes it. Thanks!